# Image Upload in Cakephp

Tags: image, function, cakephp, upload

I want to upload image from user form. But my code is not working. Please help me

My view code is here:

```
echo $this->Form->create('User',array('enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'));
echo $this->Form->input('cat_image',array('type'=>'file'));
echo $this->Form->end('Submit');
```

My Controller code is here:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['tmp_name'], WWW_ROOT . 'img/uploads/' . $_FILES['cat_image']);
```

Answer (score 7):

You have to add a 'type' tag to your form:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User', array('type' => 'file'));?>
```

Then in the Controller do something like this:

```
if (is_uploaded_file($data['User']['image']['tmp_name']))
{
    move_uploaded_file(
        $this->request->data['User']['image']['tmp_name'],
        '/path/to/your/image/dir/' . $this->request->data['User']['image']['name']
    );

    // store the filename in the array to be saved to the db
    $this->request->data['User']['image'] = $this->request->data['User']['image']['name'];
}
```

And to View  like this to show the image in webpage:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->image('/path/to/your/image/dir/' . $listShExPainImage['User']['image']); ?>
```

Let me know if i can help you more.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
echo $this->Form->create('User',array('enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'));
```

to

```
echo $this->Form->create('User',array('type' => 'file'));
```

output

<form id="UserAddForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/users/add">